# 14.04: Enabling the 2nd NIC on the server

Tags: 14.04, nic

I have read a lot of posts and tried all the suggested work but still no luck. I have a server with 2 onbord nic, em1 and em2. Both are configured as follow

```
iface em1 inet static
  role            Management
  name            Management Network
  address         10.37.72.26
  netmask         255.255.255.0
  network         10.37.72.0
  broadcast       10.37.72.255
  gateway         10.37.72.1

# The secondary network interface
auto em2
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------
iface em2 inet static
  address         10.37.73.26
  netmask         255.255.255.0
  network         10.37.73.0
  broadcast       10.37.73.255
  gateway         10.37.73.1
```

em1 and em2 are connected to 2 different network switches. em1 is on vlan 72 and em2 is online 73. I can ONLY ping 1 of the 2 interfaces, usually em1, but if I bring it down by modifying the interface file and restart I then could ping em2.

I also tried commenting the gateway and adding a static route and that did not help.

What do I need to do to have both working at the sametime ?

Comment: Please, add `ip route` output too.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic   14.04 LTS is EOL & thus off-topic, 14.04 ESM is supported only by Canonical via Ubuntu Advantage & still off-topic here

Answer (score 1):

Only one gateway should be assigned to network interface which is looking towards network with Internet access.

```
$ ip route
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlx8c882b131d84 proto dhcp metric 600 
10.190.25.0/24 dev pan1 proto kernel scope link src 10.190.25.1 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlx8c882b131d84 scope link metric 1000 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 
192.168.1.0/27 dev wlx8c882b131d84 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.4 metric 600 
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.122.1 linkdown
```

The second network should be available without additional route adding. It will be recorded automatically in the routing table as it is in my `ip route` output for every properly configured and active network interface.

Comment: Thanks Gryu. This system is not connected to the internet, it is in our LAN only. The idea is to have access to the server via 2 different Vlans.

Comment: Then try to remove two gateways and we will see what will happen. If you only have two networks and PC does not go to the internet at all, then you don't need gateways on these interfaces.

Comment: I do though between 2 vlans. I have 2 network switches (one has vlan 72 and the other one has vlan 73), em1 is connected to vlan 72 and em2 is connected to vlan 73.

Comment: Ok, I see it. But have you tried commenting two gateways for these two networks and rebooting after it?

Comment: Yeah I just tried it, same result. It very strange, with the gateways configured. I could ping both gateways and I could also ping both gateways from the server itself.

Comment: Is this server a VM? Are its network interfaces virtual or real? If a vm, what a hypervisor used?